# Hibernate Map Mapping Problem

Tags: hibernate, dictionary, hibernate-mapping

Hi I am trying to Persist a Map in Hibernate as follows:

```
public class Product{
    @OneToMany
    @MapKey(name="id")
 private Map<Company,ProductCompany> productCompanies=new HashMap<Company,ProductCompany>();

}

public class Company{
 private int id;
}
public class ProductCompany(){
 @ManyToOne
 private Product product;
 @ManyToOne
 private Company company;
}
```

Any idea what the correct annotation would be for doing this mapping? At the moment it stores the keyset as ints...not as Company objects.

Thxs.

Comment: Similar post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2327971/how-do-you-map-a-map-in-hibernate-using-annotations

Comment: That doesnt help...I am mapping an Entity as the key not a String

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using company as your MapKey:

```
public class Product{
@OneToMany
@MapKey(name="company")
private Map<Company,ProductCompany> productCompanies=new HashMap<Company,ProductCompany>();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to build your project , before executing commands