# Storing a Map<String,String> using JPA

Tags: java, jpa, orm, jpa-2.0

I am wondering if it is possible using annotations to persist the `attributes` map in the following class using JPA2

```
public class Example {
    long id;
    // ....
    Map<String, String> attributes = new HashMap<String, String>();
    // ....
}
```

As we already have a pre existing production database, so ideally the values of `attributes`  could map to the following existing table:

```
create table example_attributes {
    example_id bigint,
    name varchar(100),
    value varchar(100));
```

Answer (score 217, accepted):

JPA 2.0 supports collections of primitives through the `@ElementCollection` annotation that you can use in conjunction with the support of `java.util.Map` collections. 
Something like this should work:

```
@Entity
public class Example {
    @Id long id;
    // ....
    @ElementCollection
    @MapKeyColumn(name="name")
    @Column(name="value")
    @CollectionTable(name="example_attributes", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="example_id"))
    Map<String, String> attributes = new HashMap<String, String>(); // maps from attribute name to value

}
```

#### See also (in the JPA 2.0 specification)

- 2.6 - Collections of Embeddable Classes and Basic Types
- 2.7 Map Collections
- 10.1.11 - ElementCollection Annotation
- 11.1.29 MapKeyColumn Annotation

Comment: Is there a workaround to do this using JPA 1? I only found examples with `Map<String, SomeOtherClass>`

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that `example_attributes` should have a composite key `(example_id, name)` - which is what hbm2ddl will generate from the above.

Comment: I tried above example, but when trying to persist an entity, I am getting an exception: You must define at least one mapping for this table.
Query: InsertObjectQuery(null). Any hints?
I create an empty entity and set properties map, then trying to persist.

Comment: Using MariaDB, I ran into `Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes` doing this. The primary key it tries to create is a combination of the varchar(255) and the @JoinColumn, which exceeds the default column size. You need to either [change your database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814532/1071-specified-key-was-too-long-max-key-length-is-767-bytes) or modify your @MapKeyColumn to provide a length: `@MapKeyColumn(name="name", length=100)`

Comment: This worked for me! Had to make sure that I my table was referencing my other table's PK.

Answer (score 23):

```
  @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @CollectionTable(name = "raw_events_custom", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name =     "raw_event_id"))
  @MapKeyColumn(name = "field_key", length = 50)
  @Column(name = "field_val", length = 100)
  @BatchSize(size = 20)
  private Map<String, String> customValues = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

This is an example on how to set up a map with control over column and table names and field length.

Comment: fetch type should be *EAGER*

Answer (score 0):

```
@ElementCollection
@MapKeyColumn(name="lang_code")
@Column(name="client_name")
@CollectionTable(name="client_name_lang", 
joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="client_id"))
private Map<StringString> clientNameLangMap;
```

Key points to note:

1. @ElementCollection: Indicates that the map is a collection of
   elements that are not entities themselves.
2. @MapKeyColumn(name="lang_code"): Specifies the column in the
   collection table that will store the map's keys.
3. @Column(name="client_name"): Specifies the column in the collection
   table that will store the map's values.
4. @CollectionTable(name="client_name_lang",
   joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="client_id")): Defines the table that
   will be used to store the map. The joinColumns attribute specifies
   the foreign key column that links the map entries to the entity.

This setup will create a separate table (client_name_lang in this example) to store the map entries, with each entry consisting of a lang_code and client_name column. The client_id column in the client_name_lang table will serve as a foreign key linking each map entry back to the ClientDetail entity instance.