# Mapping Map<String,String> using Hibernate

Tags: string, hibernate, mapping

It seems that everywhere I look, there are outdated versions of this which no longer work. 
My problem seems really simple. I have a class in Java, which maps to a derby database. I'm using annotations, and have successfully managed to create all the other tables in my DB, yet with this specific example, where I just need a Map, which does not use any other class, just two simple string values. I have come across all types of errors trying everything I've found online.

Does anybody know of a simple way of doing this, without using deprecated annotations?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 16):

[Chapter 2.2.5.3.4](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html/entity.html#entity-mapping-association) of Hibernate Annotations documentation describes the necessary annotations. You need to do something like:

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity {
    ...

    @ElementCollection // this is a collection of primitives
    @MapKeyColumn(name="key") // column name for map "key"
    @Column(name="value") // column name for map "value"
    public Map<String,String> getMyMap() {

    ...
}
```

Comment: I used these annotations & made a separate entity for myMap. I am getting this error:  Can not set java.lang.Long field AttributeValueRange.id to java.lang.String. What could be the problem here?

Comment: I think it should be `@MapKeyColumn` and not `@MapKey`, the latter is used when the key is an attribute of the value.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393649/storing-a-mapstring-string-using-jpa which gives the annotations on how to customize the collection table / columns name