# Mapping HashMap as table's columns using hibernate annotation

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa

I have a hashmap:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>
```

I would like to map keys and values of hashmap to table's column. For example, if I have something like this: (key1, value1); (key2, value2), the table will look like:

```
id  key  value
1   key1 value1
2   key2 value2.
```

I've tried use something like this in my model class

```
@ElementCollection
@MapKeyColumn(name = "property")
@Column(name = "value", nullable = false)
private Map<String, String> settings = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

but it couses that hibernate creates two tables: first one with one column: id, second one with three columns id_table (foreign key to id from first column), key, value.

I will be grateful for any help.

Comment: [see if this can help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393649/storing-a-mapstring-string-using-jpa)

Comment: Can you show the containing entity?

Comment: `I would like to map keys and values of hashmap to table's column`... I still don't understand what is what you are trying to accomplish. Do you want the foreign key of the child/collection table to be an arbitrary unique column of the parent table?

Comment: @orid: thank you. I was looking for something like this.