# Alternative to @ElementCollection using JPA 1.0 for persisting Map<String,String>?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, jpa-1.0

I'm trying to persist a simple Map of attributes as a key value pair for one of my persisted objects. I found a good guide on this matter [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Relationships#Maps). But it only shows how to map when the value of the key is a mapped object (with a 'mapped by' property). My scenario is simpler than this. All I need is to persist a `Map<String, String>` for a key value pair. I found that I could use `@ElementCollection` but it is only supported on JPA 2 (the platform I'm working on is still on JPA1).

This is how my code looks like so far:

```
@Entity
public class MyClass {

    private Map<String, String> attributes;

    @OneToMany
    @MapKey(name="key")
    @JoinTable(name="MyClass_attributes")
    public Map<String, String> getAttributes () {
        return this.attributes;
    }

    public void setAttributes(Map<String, String> attributes) {
        this.attributes = attributes;
    }

}
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: 
Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting 
an unmapped class: mypackage.MyClass.attributes[java.lang.String]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a class for the map's value, like TargetClass. Then the map would be this:

```
private Map<String, TargetClass> attributes;
```

In this case the JoinTable doesn't need.

Comment: That's what I was trying to avoid. That seems to much overhead for something really simple. It would be great if I could do something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393649/storing-a-mapstring-string-using-jpa but I need a JPA 1 solution.

Comment: Well using JPA is basically dealing with overhead stuffs.

Comment: Well... since we're using Hibernate, I'll simply use `@CollectionOfElements` (org.hibernate.annotations.CollectionOfElements)