# Adding map values into database using jpa

Tags: jpa, dictionary

title says everything. Right now my code adds key values to the database, i think the problem is in my model class or servlet class. Id like to save `Map<String, String>` value into the `String customerType` field

Model :

```
@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "my_seq", sequenceName = "seq1", allocationSize = 1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "my_seq")
public long id;
private String firstName;
private String customerType;

@ElementCollection
@Column(name="customerType")
public Map<String, String> customerTypes;
```

I put values into map, using servlet class, which looks like this :

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {


    showForm(request, response);

}
private void showForm(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
{
    Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();

       map.put("","");
       map.put("customerType.private", "Private");
       map.put("customerType.corporate", "Corporate");

    Customer customer = new Customer();

    customer.setCustomerTypes(map);
    request.setAttribute("customer", customer);

    request.getRequestDispatcher("/Add.jsp").forward(request, response);    
}
```

NB! i send map values into select tag in the Add.jsp page (simple user adding form), from where the data gets saved into database. And when the data gets saved the `customerType` is in the form of `customerType.corporate` or `customerType.private`, but should be `Corporate` or `Private`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are using `@ElementCollection` in a wrong way. If this worked, how would you populate map keys when you read the entity from the database? `customerTypes` should be in a separate table, take a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393649/storing-a-mapstring-string-using-jpa) for a solution to a similar problem. Something like this

```
@ElementCollection
@MapKeyColumn(name="customer_type_key")
@Column(name="customer_type_value")
@CollectionTable(name="customer_types", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="customer_id"))
Map<String, String> attributes = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

**UPDATE**

Regarding your comment, that you want to have a field in which you would put values from the map in some format. In this case, you don't need `customerTypes` at all, but you can keep it as `@Transient` field if you need it for something.

```
@Transient
Map<String, String> attributes = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

For most trivial implementation, you can use `Map#toString()` as value for `customerType` field.

*Servlet:*

```
...
    Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();

    map.put("customerType.private", "Private");
    map.put("customerType.corporate", "Corporate");

    Customer customer = new Customer();
    customer.setCustomerType(map.toString());
...
```

`customerType`'s value after this will be `{customerType.private=Private, customerType.corporate=Corporate}`. You will need some custom logic if you want different format.

Comment: Basically you suggest me to get rid of the String customerType, and save the Map<String, String> instead? So i dont have to create another table for the map.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish. Do you want to have a collection of customer types, or just a single customer type? Or you want to have a `customerType` field in which you would put the map, in some format similar to `customerType.corporate: Corporate, customerType.private: Private`?

Comment: field in which you would put the map, in some format similar to customerType.corporate: Corporate, customerType.private: Private