# Persist a Map< Long, Boolean > with JPA/Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am not an expert in JPA/Hibernate and I really do not know if what I am trying to achieve is not possible or I am doing it wrong and since I expect that is the latter here goes nothing.

I have a Map< Long, Boolean > which I am trying to persist into a table and was following the example described here: [Storing a Map<String,String> using JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393649/storing-a-mapstring-string-using-jpa)

And other examples which basically describe the same practice.

What I was trying to do is:

```
@Id    
private Long id;

@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(name = "state_map", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id"))
@MapKeyColumn(name = "name")
@Column(name = "value")
@Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.TrueFalseType")
private Map<Long, Boolean> myBooleanMap;
```

And my table is defined as:

```
CREATE TABLE if not exists state_map
(id BIGINT NOT NULL,
name BIGINT NOT NULL,
value CHAR);
```

But then I get a HibernateException: Wrong column type in STATE_MAP for column value. Found: bigint, expected: char(255)

When I change the bigint to char(255) the entityManager starts but when I am trying to put in the map and persist I am getting a java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.Boolean.
I suppose that the @Type annotation is applied on the key column instead on the value column.

The only way I managed to make it work is with Map< String, String >. Also I have tried to do everything in the same table which did not work so I have to declare another with just the surrogate id which is mapped to the entity:

```
CREATE TABLE if not exists state_id
(id serial primary key);

@Entity
@Table(name = "state_id")
public class StateModel {...}
```

Hope somebody can help, thanks.

**UPDATE - SOLUTION**

I have solved by introducing an embeddable to wrap the boolean value column:

```
@Embeddable
class BooleanWrapper{

     @Column(name = "value")
     @Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.TrueFalseType")
     private Boolean myBoolean;}
```

And my map became:

```
@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(name = "state_map", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id"))
@MapKeyColumn(name = "name")
private Map<Long, BooleanWrapper> myBooleanMap;
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you have annotated myBooleanMap with @Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.TrueFalseType") which I think is incorrect. You can define TrueFalseType for a CHAR column  not for map. I don't think bigint is a problem

Comment: Yeah I also think this is not correct but I do not know how to say that the value column is a TrueFalseType?

Comment: For CollectionTable you cannot specify the type it will work with default type which I think is INTEGER  (0,1) for Boolean