# How to map a HashMap that contains ArrayList

Tags: java, jpa, annotations, eclipselink, jpa-2.1

I am working on a `Java` project on my spare time,

 I started using `JPA 2.1` and learning to use `annotations`.
I have a class named `Schedule` that I want to contain this field:

```
private HashMap<LocalDate, ArrayList<Lesson>> theLessons
```

Lesson is another entity in my Database, LocalDate is the Java class.
Is that possible?
I tried to do it combining @OneToMany with @MapKey like in [How do you map a "Map" in hibernate using annotations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2327971/how-do-you-map-a-map-in-hibernate-using-annotations)
but with no effect.
I am thinking that maybe I will need to create other `Entities` to facilitate this, like maybe a `ListOfLessons`, that will contain the `ArrayList<Lesson>` in order to shorten the `HashMap` to :

```
private HashMap<LocalDate, ListOfLessons>
```

Any help welcome

Comment: how do you expect this to be stored in the database? what tables, columns?

Comment: @Neil Stockton : Well that is the issue, I don't have much experience with designing DBs. I don't mind how it is saved, I just want to have this information

Comment: You need to understand and draw out the relation between what a localDate, schedule and Lesson are.  Why would a particular localDate have a list of lessons associated to it, and what is a localDate exactly?  ListofLessons would have the LocalDate and a 1:m list of Lessons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did that appears to be working fine:

```
@Entity
public class Schedule implements Serializable {
....
    @OneToMany
    @MapKey(name = "theDate")
    private Map<LocalDate, ListOfLessons> allLessons = new HashMap<>();
....
}
@Entity
public class ListOfLessons implements Serializable {
...
    private LocalDate theDate;
    @OneToMany
    private List<Lesson> allLessons = new ArrayList<>();
...
}
```

Notice that `ListOfLessons`' field called `theDate` is used as a Map Key in class `Schedule`

Answer (score 1):

Just create an intermediate "Entity" and have a Map (as you presumed) and you'll find that in any decent JPA docs.