# how to use mapBy when collection is an HashMap and not a simple List?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have the following entity which fails to create:

```
 @OneToMany( fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval=true, mappedBy="itemA" )
 @Cascade( { CascadeType.ALL } ) 
 @MapKey( name="id.customKey" )
 private Map<String, ItemB> bMap;
```

It gives me a:

```
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property
```

The ManyToOne class attribute is the following:

```
@ManyToOne( optional=false )
@NotFound( action=NotFoundAction.EXCEPTION )
@JoinColumn( name="ID_ITEM_B", nullable=false, updatable=true, insertable=true  )
private ItemA itemA;
```

This code seems working fine with a List of ItemB, problem comes when I put a Map in play...how come?

Answer (score 0):

When you use Map, just add `@MapKey( name="id.customKey" )`, do not use `mappedBy`.
see an answer here: [How do you map a "Map" in hibernate using annotations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2327971/how-do-you-map-a-map-in-hibernate-using-annotations)