# How can I annotate a map to join two seemingly unrelated classes?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, hibernate-mapping

I have a class that needs to manage a mapping of two other classes, but I need to isolate it to only the records it cares about. Basically, you have a player who might have an account on any number of game servers. Each server has to manager the player-to-account mapping for only its server. In these stub classes, I'm omitting a lot of unnecessary fields. Assume

```
// player has no collections or associations in the class
public class Player {
    @Id @GeneratedValue @Column private int id;
    // other crap about the actual person
}

// character has an association to the player and the server
public class LocalCharacter {
    @Id @GeneratedValue @Column private int id;
    @ManyToOne private Player player;
    @ManyToOne private GameServer server;
    // other crap about this person's character on this server
}

// game server needs to know who all is on it, but it needs to be mapped to the player
public class GameServer {
    @Id @GeneratedValue @Column private int id;
    @/* no idea here */ private Map<Player, LocalCharacter> localCharacters;
}
```

I'm not sure how to construct this mapping. I know if I just wanted a `Set<LocalCharacter>` I could do that with an `@OneToMany`. I know I could do a `join fetch` on the player and construct the Map myself, but that seems lame - I'd like hibernate to do it for me! :-) How can I make this happen?

Comment: What have you tried? You can't use a variation of the approach detailed in example 7.11 in the docs? (https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch07.html)

Comment: All I've tried is what I know works, making the Set and manually constructing the maps I need.

Comment: So why not try some of those map annotations?

Comment: Take a look at this auestion:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2327971/how-do-you-map-a-map-in-hibernate-using-annotations

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a [@MapKeyJoinColumn](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/MapKeyJoinColumn.html) for that:

```
public class GameServer {

    @Id 
    private Integer id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="server")       
    @MapKeyJoinColumn(name="player_id")
    private Map<Player, LocalCharacter> localCharacters = new HashMap<>();

}
```

Check this answer for a detail explanation of [various java.util.Map associations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25439813/difference-between-mapkey-mapkeycolumn-and-mapkeyjoincolumn-in-hibernate).